# How to view the changes of OneDrive children

Tags: onedrive

I want to list all the changes of a file inside a folder in OneDrive for business. I can list all the changes in root directory using the below API.

```
/drive/root/view.delta
```

The link which I am following is

[view_delta](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm)

But when I try to list the changes of a file within a folder its throwing the below error.

```
[error] => Array
        (
            [code] => notSupported
            [message] => view.delta can only be called on the root.
        )
```

The API which I am calling is below. Here Sample is a directory in root folder and Document.docx is a file within that.

```
/drive/root:/Sample/Document.docx:/view.delta
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. In OneDrive for Business, view.delta is only supported on the root folder, not on other folders. It also will not return the following Item properties:

```
createdBy
cTag
eTag
fileSystemInfo
lastModifiedBy
parentReference
size
```